# gesture.view on top [UIPanGestureRecognizer]

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I have many of views added as subview for UIScrollView where is already a subview for self.view, during dragging the object i can't see object outside of its superview (UIScrollView) and self.view thus I use bringSubviewToFront but it doesn't work

Any hint please?

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    static CGPoint originalCenter;
    static CGPoint originalforScroll;
    CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
    int viewTag = gesture.view.tag;
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [gesture.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];
        originalCenter = gesture.view.center;
        originalforScroll = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    }

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
        gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translate.x, originalCenter.y + translate.y);

    }

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
        gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
        gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
}

}
```

Comment: You have a UIScrollView.... inside that scroll view, you have subviews... you want to Pan (tap and drag) a subview from inside the scroll view to outside the scroll view? Is that correct?

Comment: @DonMag Yes correct

Comment: One method: on touch began, move the view from the scroll view to its superview. If you search for `ios drag and drop between views` you'll find many examples, libraries, extensions, etc.